# How to split large data and rejoin later

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, file-io, split

My code generates a list of numpy arrays of size (1, 1, n, n, m, m) where n may vary from 50-100 and m from 5-10 depending on the case at hand. The length of the list itself may go up to 10,000 and is being written/dumped using *pickle* at the end of the code. For cases at the higher end of these numbers or when file sizes go beyond 5-6 GB, I get *Out of Memory* error. Below is a made up example of the situation,

```
import numpy as np
list, list_length = [], 1000
n = 100
m = 3
for i in range(0, list_length):
   list.append(np.random.random((1, 1, n, n, m, m)))

file_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Temp/'
with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(list, file)
```

I am looking for a way that helps me to

- split the data so that I can get rid of memory error, and
- rejoin the data in the original form when needed later

All I could think is:

```
for i in range(0, list_length):
   data = np.random.random((1, 1, n, n, m, m))
   file_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Temp/'+str(i)
   with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
      pickle.dump(data, file)
```

and then combine using:

```
combined_list = []
for i in range(0, list_length):
    file_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Temp/single' + str(i)
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        data = pickle.load(file)
    combined_list.append(data)
```

Using this way, the file size certainly reduces due to multiple files, but that also increases processing time due to multiple file I/O operations.

Is there a more elegant and better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `savez`, `savez_compressed`, or even things like `h5py` can be useful as @tel mentioned, but that takes extra effort trying to do "reinvent" caching mechanism. There are two easier ways to process larger-than-memory `ndarray` if applicable:

- The **easiest** way is of course enable `pagefile` (or some other name) on Windows or `swap` on Linux (not sure about OS X counter part). This creates a virtually large enough memory so that you don't need to worry about memory at all. It will save to disk/load from disk accordingly
- If the first way is not applicable due to not have admin rights or etc, `numpy` provides another way: `np.memmap`. This function maps an `ndarray` to disk such that you can index it just like it is in memory. Technically IO is done directly to the hard disk but OS will cache accordingly

For the second way, you can create a hard-disk side `ndarray` using:

```
np.memmap('yourFileName', 'float32', 'w+', 0, 2**32)
```

This creates a 16GB `float32` array within no time (containing 4G numbers). You can then do IO to it. A lot of functions have an `out` parameter. You can set the `out` parameter accordingly so that the output is not "copied" to the disk from memory

If you want to save a list of `ndarray`s using the second method, either create a lot of `memmap`s, or concat them to a single array

Comment: This is something new for me. Will try it and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pickle to store large data, it's not an efficient way to serialize anything. Instead, use the built-in numpy serialization formats/functions via the [`numpy.savez_compressed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy-savez-compressed) and [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) functions.

System memory isn't infinite, so at some point you'll still need to split your files (or use a heavier duty solution such as the one provided by the [`h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html) package). However, if you were able to fit the original list into memory then `savez_compressed` and `load` should do what you need.

Comment: I will try this solution. But can I save list of arrays with this method. Doc mentions it has to be arrays.

Comment: I just tried with np.savez_compressed. It takes 7 times more time to evaluate, for n=50, m=3, list_length = 1000, which is a low end case.

Comment: Just do `np.savez_compressed('filename', *l)` to save a list `l` of arrays. If it's taking too long, you can trade off speed vs size-on-disk to some extent by using the `np.savez` function instead.